# Single-line vs. Multi-line Send

Tags: autohotkey

I faced with a very strange problem about how the Send command works.

Here is my script, which will emulate Control-Click. (For sites, where Control-Click is disabled).

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
SetKeyDelay, 2000 ; Just for testing. In future, here should be something more fast and reliable
^LButton::
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    if state = D
    {
        Send, {Click Right}
        Send, {Down}
        Send, {Enter}
    }
return
#IfWinActive
```

This script is far from being final version, it slow, it is not very reliable, but generally, it works. You could test it, for example, on the main page of StackOverflow.

But if I place all send commands on the single line, that is:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
SetKeyDelay, 2000
^LButton::
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    if state = D
        Send, {Click Right}{Down}{Enter}
return
#IfWinActive
```

then the "Down" keypress sometimes scrolling the page, instead of selecting the menu item ("Open link in new tab").

Why it happens? And how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

1. {Click Right} isn't considered a key press and isn't affected by SetKeyDelay.
2. {Click Right} isn't clicking precisely on the link
3. {Click Right} is executing before the page is ready

Regardless, you should be able to replace `Send, {Click Right}{Down}{Enter}` with:

```
MouseClick Middle
```

This tells chrome to opens a link in a new tab

Comment: I should test it in real life site. There were few ones where Ctrl-Click was disabled, but I can't find them right now. But isn't single vs multiline Send difference is a bit weird? Is it something like AHK bug? (I saw that difference a lot of times, in many scripts).

Comment: It seems like AHK has many features related to sending keystrokes using different methods.  There's send, sendinput, sendplay, sendraw and a big batch of configuration settings that modify how sendXXXX behaves.  And what works in one version of Windows doesn't necessarily work in other versions. I think AHK has really bent over backwards trying to accommodate the inconsistencies in the Windows platforms, so in my opinion, it's not so much a "bug" as a best effort.  Working with AHK for me less about learning the *correct* way of doing stuff as for simply finding one way that works.

Comment: "Working with AHK [...]" - Excellent quote. That is also my feelings of using AHK in comparison with more-or-less predictable JS and Python. I know about difference between different Send modes, but this single-multi line issue is never mentioned in official docs. That's why I call it "weird".